# Init a serial communication with c library open() causes TX to send one bit on RPi

Tags: c, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a serial communication between the RPI and an FPGA. However, there is an issue when using the standard C library open() to init the serial interface: I'm using a scope to monitor what is sent and received via the RX and TX lines. A call to open causes the TX line of the RPI to go low for the length of one bit. I do not see this behavior with other computers/linux PCs. The point is, the FPGA assumes a valid transmission, since he thinks it's a start bit, but it's not.

I checked with minicom installed on the RPI. Same thing. Starting minicom causes the TX line sending one bit. Once minicom has started, the communication runs as expected and all bytes have the correct frame size. Is there any way to suppress the TX line going low upon the open call to init the serial communication? Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a super far-fetched hunch, but [this code](https://github.com/bootc/linux/blob/rpi-3.2.23/drivers/tty/serial/amba-pl011.c#LC1395) seems a bit suspicious, from the `pl011_startup()` function in the PL011 [serial port driver](https://github.com/bootc/linux/tree/rpi-3.2.23/drivers/tty/serial):

```
/*
 * Provoke TX FIFO interrupt into asserting.
 */
```

It *seems* as if it's twiddling the TX line when starting up the port, which would explain the pulse you're seeing. More investigation would surely be needed before concluding this is what happens, of course.

So, I guess my "answer" boils down to: that sounds weird, perhaps it's something with the driver?

Of course, one way of working around this is to apply some care in the FPGA end, assuming you have more control over it. "Proper" framing would take care of this, and make it clear that the spurious send can be discarded.

**UPDATE**: I meant that if "proper" messages were to be always framed by some sequence of bytes, the FPGA might be able to discard invalid ("unframed") data anyway, and thus become immune to the random pulse. For instance, messages could be defined to always start with `SOH` (start of header) or `SOT` (start of text) symbols ([bytes with the values 0x01 and 0x02](http://www.asciitable.com/), respectively).

Comment: Thx. Looked at the code you hinted to. Although I did not understand in all detail what it does, it might be the direction to look to. On the FPGA side it's not easy since the timing between the "spike" and real data depends on the C-code between the open() and write(). Will check with a fox-g20 board running debarm.

Comment: Your suggestion works with an additional header and some timing adjustments. Posted a bug report.  thanks.