# Linux Remove UART extra characters

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, uart, tty

Working on linux, sending data to the serial port at 115200 bauds using:

```
echo -e "\x1B\x11\x00\x00" > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

The receiver side is reading the following data:

```
\xF8\x1B\x11\x00\x00\x0D\x0A
```

I dont want `\xF8` as starting byte and `\x0D\x0A` as tails (carriage return and new line bytes).
How could I remove them? So far all I found is

```
stty raw -F /dev/ttyAMA0
```

This deactivates the `\x0D`, but i want to get rid of `\xF8` and `\x0A` and no other options have worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the newline with `echo -en`. Or use `printf` instead.

Are you sending from a raspberry pi? It seems to be a known issue that `0xF8` is sent each time the connection is opened (e.g. by calling `echo`). I don't know if there's a fix but you can keep the connection open to prevent further `0xF8`'s by using a serial terminal program.

There's an example in the third post here that shows how to keep the connection using a redirection in bash: `exec 9> /dev/ttyAMA0`
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=34528&p=293067

**The underlying problem:**
Some say it's a driver issue (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14581355/1442598)) but as far as i understand, the following indicates that it's hardware related:

> http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection#Glitch_when_opening_serial_port
>   When the serial port is opened the voltage on TXD pulses negative for approximately 32 us (regardless of the baud rate). This pulse may be interpreted as a transmission by a device connected to the TXD pin, which could have unintended effects.

This also means that the garbage you receive is dependant on the baud rate. I wouldn't rely on a fix and look for a workaround instead.

If you have control over the receiver, you could make it wait for a self-defined sequence of bytes and only start operating after this sequence has been received.

The link to elinux.org above could give you some other ideas.

Comment: Thanks @1000ml this will do the work. Im working on a raspberry pi running latest raspbian. I believe the broadcom chip is in charge of managing the UART. Do you think it may be possible Broadcom will fix the bug?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: This is the definitely the most complete answer I could wish. Thanks 1000 ml

Answer (score -2):

**EDITED***

what about using stty to change how your device terminal is interpreting carriage return and newline character?

link

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ustty.htm

********************OLD ANSWER*******************

What about using sed to remove "\xF8" and "\x0D\x0A"?

```
 sed -e 's/\\x0D\\x0A$//g' -e 's/^\\xF8//g' my_file > new_file
```

**pratical example?**

```
echo '\xF8\x1B\x11\x00\x00\x0D\x0A' |sed -e 's/\\x0D\\x0A$//g' -e 's/^\\xF8//g'
```

**output**

```
\x1B\x11\x00\x00
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the question properly.

Comment: i am trying to help.don't know much about porting and bauds however i found an interesting article..the link is in my edited answer..hope this helps

Comment: The `stty` man page?  I'm sorry, but I don't think that contributes, either.  The OP had already discovered that.

Comment: well tiplee since you are so good at your criticism of me trying to help..why not give us the solution?? or you don't know the answer??...easier said than done triplee..